# Split filename and get the element between first and last occurrence of underscore

Tags: bash, for-loop, split, substring

I am trying to split many folder names in a for loop and extract the element between first and last underscore of filename. Filenames can look like ENCSR000AMA_HepG2_CTCF or ENCSR000ALA_endothelial_cell_of_umbilical_vein_CTCF.

My problem is that folder names differ form each other in the total number of underscores, so I cannot use something like:

```
IN=$d
folderIN=(${IN//_/ })
tf_name=${folderIN[-1]%/*} #get last element which is the TF name
cell_line=${folderIN[-2]%/*}; #get second last element which is the cell line
dataset_name=${folderIN[0]%/*}; #get first element which is the dataset name
```

cell_line can be one or more words separated by underscore but it's allways between 1st and last underscore.

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do this in a two step bash parameter expansion *ONLY* because `bash` does not support nested parameter expansion unlike `zsh` or other shells.

`"${string%_*}"` to strip the everything after the last occurrence of '_' and `"${tempString#*_}"` to strip everything from beginning to first occurrence of '_'

```
string="ENCSR000ALA_endothelial_cell_of_umbilical_vein_CTCF"
tempString="${string%_*}"
printf "%s\n" "${tempString#*_}"
endothelial_cell_of_umbilical_vein
```

Another example,

```
string="ENCSR000AMA_HepG2_CTCF"
tempString="${string%_*}"
printf "%s\n" "${tempString#*_}"
HepG2
```

You can modify this logic to apply on each of the file-names in your folder.

Answer (score 0):

Could use regex.

```
extract_words() {
    [[ "$1" =~ ^([^_]+)_(.*)_([^_]+)$ ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"
}

while read -r from_line
do
    extracted=$(extract_words "$from_line")
    echo "$from_line" "[$extracted]"
done < list_of_filenames.txt
```

EDIT: I moved the "extraction" into an alone bash function for reuse and easy modification for more complex cases, like:

```
extract_words() {
        perl -lnE 'say $2 if /^([^_]+)_(.*)_([^_]+)$/' <<< "$1"
}
```

Comment: You don't need the command substitution; just let `extract_words` call the `[[` command; `BASH_REMATCH` is set globally so you can write `extract_words "$from_line" && extracted=${BASH_REMATCH[2]}`.

Comment: @chepner sure. But only if you using builtin bash regexes. If someone replaces the `extract_words's` content for example with some `awk` or `perl` (for more complex scenarios) then the command substitution will be needed. As I wrote, it is designed for easy modification. (and because the substitution in fact calling a bash function, it does'nt hurts) :D

Comment: That would be the problem of the person making the change to `extract_words`. I don't think accommodating future modifications to the code is worth the overhead of a fork where it isn't necessary.

Comment: @chepner okay, fair enough. The main point, e.g. answering the OP's question, how to extract the wanted string is answered. It could be done using bash_regexes, in one pass. All fluff around is up to reader... :)